# OPENCV in JAVA and c++

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am working on an Ubuntu System.
Currently I am working on image processing through a OPENCV c++ program. I want to create an UI and link the program to that.
Since the creation of UI is much easier in JAVA I thought of changing to c++ program to JAVA.
But I did not get any proper documentation for OPENCV in JAVA.

Is it better to convert the image processing program to JAVA for UI or is it better to create a UI in c++?
Can anyone suggest a solution?

regards,
shiksha

Comment: If you want to creat an UI, use Qt , you'll than program in c++, and it works great with openc

Comment: +1 for using Qt. Coding GUI in Qt is very similar to JAVA, easy while much faster and native.